# How to compile and install iperf on a MIPS based router?

Tags: linux, software-installation, compiling, router, mips

I have a DIR-825 router based on Atheros AR7161 (MIPS) running DD-WRT v24-sp2 std. How can I compile and install iperf on it? Can I compile it directly on the target device, or do I have to cross compile it and then transfer the binary to the target device? Is this possible, and where do I begin? What kind of tools do I need? What's involved in doing something like this?

*Side note: I have limited knowledge of Linux, so please provide as thorough answer as possible, and not just some external links. If you do post a link, make sure it links to some article or a blog post that thoroughly explains the process.*

Comment: Do Linux based firmwares like DD-WRT have a native compiler? So far I have only found the source files (e.g. iperf-3.0.tar.gz) for iperf. If there is no native compiler, then chances are that I will need to cross compile that with x86 as host and MIPS as target. I will need a cross compiling environment set up on my desktop. This seems like a very complicated and time consuming task. So for now, I will probably put this on the shelf among other unfinished projects. If there's another way to run iperf on DD-WRT, please fill me in.

Comment: Well I have had the same problem , and I've just been told there is the `ipkg` packages in the following path. http://bin.entware.net/ . Choose your chipset and run accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, [Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki) is a repository (replaces Optware) of pre-compiled software packages for embedded devices. It requires that you install Entware, which is not well supported on Atheros based routers running on DD-WRT. I have not tried it myself, but running OpenWRT seems to pave the way for a more reliable and successful installation of Entware and then the `iperf` or any of the other binaries for your specific router.